# Change the number of rows and columns in the TTY

Tags: linux, terminal, console, tty

I want to resize the terminal which comes up when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd>,<kbd>F3</kbd>,...). 25x80 is small for a 24" screen.

Tried using stty, but the commands `stty columns 200` and `stty rows 50` does not work directly. Am I missing something OR is this a wrong approach.

Ideally looking for a generalized solution, but would be content with something that works in RHEL5 and Ubuntu. It would be better if its possible using some commands which I can put in a script file rather than changing some boot-level stuff.

Comment: @jasonwryan, I checked that solution, but it involves modification of `grub.conf`. As I mentioned, I would prefer something which does not involve tinkering with boot-time files.

Comment: You can change the size of the font without touching grub's config...

Comment: yes, you probably can—but that other answer doesn't tell you how, and that's what I was looking for, too.  I don't mind my console coming up with a tiny font most of the time, but right now, I want it bigger!

Answer (score 12):

There are two major types of glass console on Linux: graphical and text modes.

You get graphical consoles if your video subsystem is supported by the Linux kernel directly, and you have enabled this / have not disabled this (depends on the distribution). If there's a driver, your screen will be autodetected and you'll get (by default) 9×16 pixel text at its native resolution. Then you'll have the opposite problem: tiny text. If `CONFIG_FONTS` and `CONFIG_FONTS_*` is enabled in the kernel, you can change the boot-time font to something larger, or you can just load a larger font after the system boots. There are two ways to change the resolution itself if it fails to autodetect:

- The ‘gods, I feel so old’ way, with the kernel command line argument `vga=`, [as detailed in this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=258484). You'd need to reconfigure your boot loader for this, of course. The `vga=` option can get you both text (modes < 256) and VESA-compatible graphics modes (modes ≥ 256). The latter will be graphical but unaccelerated, so scrolling a very large framebuffer may look interesting, for slow values of ‘interesting’.
- The new way, using [Kernel Mode Setting](https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModesetting). If you learn one of these, learn this one unless you're doing a lot of embedded or retro work. The `vga=` method may go away at some point.

If your video card isn't supported, its driver isn't loaded, etc, you'll find yourself with a text mode console. Text mode consoles are limited by the range of text modes of your graphics card. 80×25, 80×43 and 80×50 are the standard VGA ones. The original non-IBM VGA and SVGA cards always had nice additional text modes, but modern cards generally don't (‘who'd ever want text?’). There's a solution here: you can manipulate the VGA registers directly to reprogram the CRTC part of the chip to get higher resolutions. A 90s program called [SVGATextMode](http://ftp.vim.org/ftp/ibiblio/utils/console/) could do this for you without kernel reconfiguration. It was a tiny bit like `xrandr`, but for text consoles, and may still work for you. I loved it: I could get something bizarre like 100×37 on my crappy 14" CRT. It made it decent for development back in 1994. To set a mode at boot time, your only recourse is to use `vga=` and use a VESA mode.

About the `stty` command: it tells the kernel *about* your terminal, but can't change the terminal itself. `stty rows 200` will tell the kernel your remotely attached glass terminal has 200 lines per screen. Why this is the case is [explained in the answers to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con).

Comment: I upgraded to kernel 4.4.49-16 (64bits) (with openSuse 42.2) and "vga=ask" started resulting in a error on startup (something as ask option not supported, I have not taken note of the exact sentence). Other options still result in no error, but anyway none of them seem to work for me (I'll take a look at the kernel mode one of these days...)

Comment: Oh. Wait. It worked. But I had to reboot twice?... Not sure, I reboot rarely, maybe I did not on the first try...

Comment: thanks for mentioninng the `vga=` option